# Rails API + VueJS Server Layout Architecture

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, server, digital-ocean

I have a Rails API only app that is being used for the backend and two VueJS apps that I am using as the front ends. Both Vuejs apps make a number of calls to the Rails API. I am also considering deploying to Digital Ocean.

My question is: What is best practice to layout a server architecture seeing that I'm using rails and vuejs. I was thinking of keeping it very separate but could be overkill and repetitive, anyone else have any thoughts?

**Vuejs App 1**

```
LoadBalancer -- Web Server 1
                Web Server 2
```

**Vuejs App 2**

```
LoadBalancer -- Web Server 1
                Web Server 2
```

**Rails API**

```
LoadBalancer -- Web Server 1
                Web Server 2
                Worker Server
                Postgres
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you need to load balance the Vue app since its just static minified files you send once to each user right? I mean unless you are planning on  billions of hits I think that might be overkill?

Depending on the amount of traffic and complexity of the API it makes sense that that's where the load balancing needs to happen if anywhere.

I have just done this exact same thing using Rails as the api for a Vue SPA and I used AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

If you haven't used it before I highly recommend it! It makes deployment and scaling an absolute breeze!

So here was my set up:

`Vue SPA - served directly from S3`

`RDS Database instance x 1 - Part of EB out of the box`

`Load balancer - Part of the EB out of the box`

`App Server x 4 - EC2 Instances out of the box with EB`

All the above is stupidly easy to configure and you can change the size of your servers, or the number you have running in just a few clicks. It really does make this whole process fantastically easy. And deployment of your app is as easy as `eb deploy` :)

One word of warning, watch the default sizes and number of servers a fresh EB setup gives you, I did spend more money than I anticipated in the first month since I was running much larger servers than I actually needed.